# Is there a way to attach a pygame window to glade window in quickly?

Tags: application-development, python, quickly, pygtk, glade

I am trying to develop a game so that when i press a button which is created using glade window i should be able to run the pygame window i have succeeded so far but the pygame window opens separately and when i close that even the window developed using glade gets closed.
  Can anyone propose a solution to my problem??

Answer (score 0):

According [pygame GUI](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/gui) section it's difficult task:

> pygame relies on the SDL, which means that it can only have one window
>   at a time. Thus, trying to implement multiple Gtk, Qt, ... application
>   instances that use pygame, is an impossibility.

I would recommend move your buttons into pygame by drawing them yourself or try to use third-party libraries like [PGU](https://code.google.com/p/pgu/).